# Versioning between App API and Database

Tags: database, api, azure, version, versioning

I have the following scenario ...

Two versions of the application that accesses an API, running version 1.0 and 1.1. The idea is to go back to version 1.0 if the 1.1 version presents problems.The API should be versioned for each of these versions too

I would like to know the solutions that are being used nowadays to make this process easily and in a safe way. 
Also, supposing we are using entity framework, how to solve the migration problem, if version 1.1 of the API has database changes?

I use ASP.NET Web API and SQL Database, both in Azure.